# data migration from one database to another after doing transformation on data

Tags: database

I have db with existing data and i want to create a new db using the existing data  with some transfomartion on it.I have millions of records whats the best procedure to do this data migration i mean should be within hours not days.

Comment: What kind of db do you have? Oracle. Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: What database platform are you migrating from/to? MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?  Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I'm using oracle.Right now ,I'm getting data from first database,transforming the data and moving it to second database using java and hibernate.This works fine but, i'm worried about the time it takes for each record.i have millions of records, in the best case even if it takes 1 sec for all this to happen think of how much time it will take for millions of records and worried about sync too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Informatica tool. Very useful for tasks like that.